# Visual Studio's git integration can't find the history of my files

Tags: git, visual-studio

Recently when I try to view the history of my code files in Visual Studio, it tells me there is no history, even though I have been making changes to them.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that some folders had changed capitalization (e.g. Src became src). Changing them back so that they match the origin repo restored the history.